# VB .Net concatenation/loop

Tags: vb.net

I have this line of code which I want to concatenate -or at least solve the loop problem...

```
test = 1 - ("0." & thisnumber(0) & thisnumber(1) & thisnumber(2) & thisnumber(3) ... thisnumber(500) )
```

I want this to have a loop in it...

I simply want to get all the array values into 1 variable sort of thing, -as it is too long for a decimal.
-So I want it to loop and work test out.

-Increasing thisnumber() (-Which is an array holding values e.g. 2,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,1)

Until it gets to about 500,

Can some implement a loop into this?

Or suggest a way.

Comment: How can I get a loop to increase the value of thisnumber's array position? -I only want test to be found out once, -dont loop the whole thing. I just want the brackets looped (increasing of the array position).

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET concatenation problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086430/vb-net-concatenation-problem)

Comment: please, do not repost the same questions.

Comment: To many people got confused by my question, i've improved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forgive the untested C# syntax:

```
var intArray = new StringBuilder();
intArray.Append("0.")
foreach(var number in thisnumber)
{
  intArray.Append(number.toString());
}
var test = 1- Double.Parse(intArray.toString());
```

Comment: So if I had values thisnumber(0) = 1, thisnumber(1) = 5, thisnumber(2) = 0, thisnumber(3) = 7... It would do 1 - 0.1507?

Comment: I didn't test it, but that's the idea.  I don't know what kind of precision `Double` data type has off the top of my head, but this should get you started.

Comment: Using Decimal.Parse() may be more precise.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/921a8ffc-9829-4145-bdc9-a96c1ec174a5/

Answer (score 0):

Use a [generic List(of Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) for this because its much more readable and performant.
Add your numbers to the list, then iterate through it and append the numbers to a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using LINQ (though I'm not clear what the `1 - (...` portion is supposed to be, since you cannot subtract a string from a number).

To deal with the relevant portion of your question--"looping" the array access portion:

```
Dim data As String = String.Join((From Idx in Enumerable.Range(0, 500) Select thisnumber(Idx).ToString()).ToArray(), "")
```

That will concatenate all of the elements of the array into a single string.

This addresses the literal requirement of your question (looping only the array access part), but I would recommend you go with another, more readable solution, such as the `StrinBuilder`-based approach that another user has already outlined.

Answer (score 0):

string.Concat will take an array of strings...

```
double d = 0.0;
string[] values = new[] { "1", "4", "0", "9" };

d = 1 - double.Parse(string.Concat("0.", string.Concat(values)));
```